# How to count occurrences of one column based on even value in another column?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two columns, one containing a storage code and another containing a location code. The first four digits of the location code give the aisle number and the 5th and 6th determine what side of the aisle the location is (even on the left, odd on the right). I want to count the number of times a storage code occurs on each side of the aisle, but am not even sure where to start. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please provide - database platform, and example input table data, and expected output.

Comment: As an aside, I would also recommend initiating a design change to split the components of the 6 digit magic composite into separate columns in the database. It will make future queries / logic work like this so much easier in future.

Comment: I'm using Access, and I'm not sure how to create tables on SO but I'll do my best to describe. The input is one table with a storage type and corresponding sizes of that type, and a second table with a location code and a column that tells the storage code that goes there. I need a count of how many of each storage codes appear on the even side of the aisle and how many on the odd side. @StuartLC Unfortunately I didn't create the database and can't modify it so I'm stuck with what I have

Answer (score 1):

Standard SQL should be:

```
Select case when side=1 then 'left' else 'right' end,count( 1)
from( select  cast(right( cast(id_LOC as text),2) as integer ) % 2 Side 
     from YourTable Name) a 
group by side
```

EDITED: for Access sound like (in this example I assume that the whole code is numeric):
REDITED: if you want groupped also for storage_Code just add it

```
SELECT storage_Code, [ID] Mod 2 AS side, count(1) 
FROM Sistema group by storage_Code, [ID] Mod 2 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

No sample data to work with, this is my stab at it

```
select count(storage_code), storage_code
from table 
where MOD(location_code,2) = 0
group by storage_code
```

Comment: Fwiw, I ran your query in the SQL Fiddle I used, in case someone wants to look at it "live": http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e50a3/13

Comment: In Access SQL, `MOD` is an operator not a function.  `where location_code MOD 2 = 0`

Comment: @Mike, nice sqlfiddle.

Comment: @HansUp, he hadnt posted a dbms when I posted this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I made up some data that hopefully is similar enough to your stuff to be useful, but how about [something like this (SQL Fiddle)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e50a3/12)?

In short, the query I did is this:

```
SELECT
  storage_code,
  SUM(location_code % 2) as RightSide,  -- Odd
  SUM( IF(location_code % 2, 0, 1) ) as LeftSide -- Even
FROM
  stuff
GROUP BY
  storage_code
```